# Scala json parsing remove outer quotes

Tags: json, scala

I'm using Jackson lib for parsing json in Scala
the data looks like :

`{"line":"SUK\t172\t7715\t12337429049\t\t7382738\tTRUE\t5\t0\t\n","file":"file1.txt"}`
when I parse it:

`val text = (parse(jstr) \ "line").extract[String]`
I'm getting : `"SUK\t172\t7715\t12337429049\t\t7382738\tTRUE\t5\t0\t\n"`and then when splitting on the tabulation first and last quote is part of the result:

field1 = "SUK

fieldn = 0"

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the quotes with simple function:

```
def dropQuotes(str: String) = {if(Seq(str.head, str.last,'\"').distinct.size == 1) str.tail.dropRight(1) else str}

val text = (parse(jstr) \ "line").extract[String]  
val textNoQuotes = dropQuotes(text)
```

Comment: This method is a bit unsafe, it would explode if the String was empty for example. Also I think you overcomplicated a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This should be just a plain and simple `text.replace("\"","")`.

If you are worried that it may have quotes on the middle of it, and want to keep them, then do the this instead:

```
def safeDropQuotes(str: String) = if(str.startsWith("\"") && str.endsWith("\"")) str.tail.dropRight(1) else str
```

Basically is the safe version the the method that @Ofek Hod wrote, it won't explode if the String is empty.